# ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 10 and 1. Shapes are [10] and [1]

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I am creating a LSTM network. i have my input pad sequenced array of shape (1400,17640),mask array (1400,17640) and y(target array) of shape(1400,) though target has 10 different class value.(1-10).
So I defined my output dense layer with 10 unit and loss as sparsecategoricalcrossentropy.
LSTM Network Code:-

```
pad_seq = np.random.rand(17640,1)

def create_model():

#input 1 (pad sequence)
input_layer1 = Input(shape=(17640,1),name = 'input_layer',dtype='float32')

#input 2 (mask)
input_layer2 = Input(shape=(17640,),name='input_mask',dtype='bool')

#LSTM layer
LSTM_layer = LSTM(25,return_sequences=False,name = 'LSTM_layer')(input_layer1,mask = input_layer2)

#Dense layer
dense = Dense(50,activation='relu',kernel_initializer=he_normal(),kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0001),name = 'dense')(LSTM_layer)

#output layer
dense_1 = Dense(10, activation = 'softmax',name='dense_1')(dense)

#concat = concatenate([input_layer,input_mask])

model = Model([input_layer1, input_layer2],dense_1)

#compile
model.compile(loss='SparseCategoricalCrossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001,decay = 1e-4),metrics=[tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes = 10)])

return model
```

But on fitting the model I am getting value error:

```
ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 10 and 1. Shapes are [10] and [1]. for '{{node AssignAddVariableOp_5}} = AssignAddVariableOp[dtype=DT_FLOAT](AssignAddVariableOp_5/resource, Cast_6)' with input shapes: [], [1].
```

Which two input shape are compared to each other which should match in order to fit model

Comment: Please provide dummy input with `np.random.rand(17640, 1)` so we can copy paste your code and reproduce the error.

Comment: @NicolasGervais I have edited the code.